# Creating .appxbundle using msbuild for (x86|x64|ARM)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, winrt-xaml

i am trying to create .appxbundle using msbuild from developer command prompt
i am using below command to create the same

```
MSBuild KitabooBookshelf.sln /p:Configuration=Release;OutDir=..\Release\;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM"
```

but getting below processor architecture error. I did not find much useful resource related to this issue though many have faced similar issue. I am new to Windows store Application. trying to figure what i am doing wrong & how can i create .appxbundle using msbuild

> "E:\Kitaboo Windows 8.1 2nd June
>   2015\KitabooBookShelf\KitabooBookshelf.csproj"  (default target) (1)
>   ->
>
> "E:\Kitaboo Windows 8.1 2nd June
>   2015\DatabaseLibrary\DatabaseLibrary.csproj" ( default target) (3) ->
>
> (ResolveSDKReferences target) ->   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targe
>   ts(1803,5): error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project
>   being buil t "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK
>   "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=1
>   2.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your proj ect (in Visual Studio this can be done through the
>   Configuration Manager) to on e of the architectures supported by the
>   SDK: "x86, x64, ARM". [E:\Kitaboo Windo ws 8.1 2nd June
>   2015\DatabaseLibrary\DatabaseLibrary.csproj]
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targe
>   ts(1803,5): error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project
>   being buil t "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK
>   "SQLite.WinRT81, Version=3.9 .2". Please consider changing the
>   targeted processor architecture of your proje ct (in Visual Studio
>   this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one  of the
>   architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM".
>
> [E:\Kitaboo Window s 8.1 2nd June
>   2015\DatabaseLibrary\DatabaseLibrary.csproj]

Answer (score 3):

I am finally spending few hours able to solve this issue

Below is the command to create x86, ARM ,x64 bundle but it creates three .Appx file each for three different architecture. msbuild does not create single bundle .appxbundle

```
E:\Project Dir>MSBuild Project.sln /p:Configuration=Release;OutDir=..\Release\;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM
```

Architecture error which i had above due to "Any CPU" i removed all "Any CPU" instance from .csproj and .sln file & replaced them with x86. and run above command i was able to creae .appx bundle for x86, ARM, x64.  before running above msbuild command do not forget to remove Bin & obj folders from project which you will find after clicking show all button on main project.

I hope this helps to someone having similar issue.

Thanks

Comment: My problem was that we added references to the Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement SDK in our UWP Class Library.